# MySQL show data if value greater than average

Tags: mysql

I have this query where I want to select or show authors whose number of books is above the average.

So far, the query I got to get the average number of books is the following:

```
SELECT AVG(c.quantity) AS 'Average'
FROM(
SELECT al.autores_DNI AS 'Author',COUNT(*) AS 'quantity'
FROM autores_has_libros AS al
GROUP BY al.autores_DNI
) AS c
```

How can I then select (show) only those authors whose number of books is above the average?

This query lists the authors with their number of books:

```
SELECT al.autores_DNI AS 'Author',COUNT(*) AS 'quantity'
    FROM autores_has_libros AS al
    GROUP BY al.autores_DNI
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT a.first_name 
FROM autores AS a
HAVING (
SELECT al.autores_DNI AS 'Author',COUNT(*) AS 'quantity'
    FROM autores_has_libros AS al
    GROUP BY al.autores_DNI
)
> (
SELECT AVG(c.quantity) AS 'Average'
    FROM(
    SELECT al.autores_DNI AS 'Author',COUNT(*) AS 'quantity'
    FROM autores_has_libros AS al
    GROUP BY al.autores_DNI
    ) AS c
)
```

But that doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first subquery in the `HAVING` clause isn't returning just the count of the current author, it's returning the counts of all others. But a `SELECT` used as a value can only return one value.

Instead, you should join with the subquery.

```
SELECT a.first_name
FROM aotores AS a
JOIN (
    SELECT al.autores_DNI AS Author,COUNT(*) AS quantity
    FROM autores_has_libros AS al
    GROUP BY Author) AS al ON al.Author = a.DNI
JOIN (
    SELECT AVG(c.quantity) AS Average
    FROM (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS quantity
        FROM autores_has_libros AS al
        GROUP BY al.autores_DNI) AS c
) AS av ON al.quantity > av.Average
```

BTW, in MySQL you quote identifiers using backticks, not single quotes. Single quotes are for creating literal strings.

Comment: All right, i just don't know how to fix the error on line 6, it says `GROUP BY al.autores_DNI) AS al ON al.autores_DNI = a.DNI:  unknown column al.autores_DNI after ON clause. error 1054` :/

Comment: I didn't notice that you had aliased the column to `Author`, so you have to use that in the `ON` clause.

Comment: That did the trick! Oh yes, you're right: backticks for identifiers. Single quotes for literal strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can try saving average in a variable and then do a select with that:

```
Set @avg = SELECT AVG(c.quantity) AS 'Average'
FROM(
SELECT al.autores_DNI AS 'Author',COUNT(*) AS 'quantity'
FROM autores_has_libros AS al
GROUP BY al.autores_DNI
) AS c

SELECT al.autores_DNI AS 'Author',COUNT(*) AS 'quantity'
FROM autores_has_libros AS al where COUNT(*) >= @avg
```

I'm not really sure if this will work, but you can have an idea with this.

Comment: There's an error after `SET` : `There's no delimiter around SET`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the result by using one sql statement, you can try following sql:

```
SELECT a.first_name FROM autores AS a 
RIGHT JOIN 
(
    SELECT autores_DNI AS Author, COUNT(*) AS quantity
    FROM autores_has_libros WHERE quantity > (
        SELECT AVG(quantity) AS Average FROM
        (
            SELECT autores_DNI AS Author, COUNT(*) AS quantity
            FROM autores_has_libros
            GROUP BY autores_DNI
        )
    )
    GROUP BY autores_DNI
) b ON a.author = b.Author
```

But, I suggest that you can use language code to get average before comparison, or using mysql procedure.