# Find all employees who earn more than the average salary of all employees of their company

Tags: mysql

I have the following database scheema.
employee (employee-name, street, city)
works (employee-name, company-name, salary)
company (company-name, city)
manages (employee-name, manager-name)

what is the query of Find all employees who earn more than the average salary of all employees of their company from the scheema?

Comment: *"what is the query?"* -> [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and also see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Hint: research corelated subqueries or a self inner join because that is what you need..

Comment: ```SELETE IF( salary > avg(salary) , "YES", "NO") From table;``` you can write your query like this. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_if.asp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL show data if value greater than average](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52864807/mysql-show-data-if-value-greater-than-average)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT employee-name FROM works WHERE salary > (SELECT AVG(salary) FROM works);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct employee_name

from 
(select company_name, avg(salary) as avg

from works

group by company_name; 
 
) as avg_company_salary join works on avg_company_salary.company_name = works.company_name

where works.salary > avg_company_salary.avg;
```

// NOTE we need to compare each employee salary with average salary of its particular company.

The inner subquery returns the table containing company_name and corresponding average salary of that company , which is then compared with each individuals salary having same company_name as that of in the avg_company_salary table.

Answer (score 0):

Select employee-name <--use * for all details--> from works where salary > (select avg(salary) from works) group by company-name;

As we have all the required data (employee name, salary, comp name) in works table so no need of join. We can directly run the query on this table.